# Excel Conditional Formatting (Range vs single cell)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to change the color of the cells in a row, if one of those cells is greater than the other cells in that specific row.

[image]

So under amount, there will be amount and each person will put in their own amounts under their initials, I want the person who puts the most to turn green. Is this possible with a range like I4:K4 or will I have to go through each cell and have a different rule for each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight the range I4:K4 then in Conditional Formatting | Use a formula put in the following

```
=I4=MAX($I4:$K4)
```

and choose a fill colour with the Format button. Then as it is extended across it will apply to any cells (could be more than one) which are equal to the maximum amount.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Conditional Formatting** dialog, and select the "**Use formula to determine which cell to format**" option. There you could use something like the formula `I4=MAX($I4:$K4)` to determine which cell to format green.